# Does closing a channel block until the receiver read it

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I've implemented a method to shutdown my server by closing a channel, so other goroutines read the closed channel then exit. After the shutdown, I need to do some cleaning with server data, if `close()` blocks until all other goroutines read the closed channel, I can access the data without lock. So the question is: does closing a channel block until the receiver read from it? Below is the example code:

```
package main

type server struct {
    chStop chan struct{}
    data map[int]interface{}
}

func newServer() *server {
    return &server {
        chStop: make(chan struct{})
    }
}

func (s *server) stop() {
    close(s.chStop)
    // do something with s.data
    ...
    // if other goroutines already read closed s.chStop and exited,
    // we can access s.data without lock
}

func (s *server) run2() {
    ...
    for {
        select{
        case <-s.chStop:
            return
        case <- other channel:
        // access s.data with lock
        }
    }
}

func (s *server) run() {
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    ...
    for {
        select{
        case <-s.chStop:
            return
        case <- ch:
            // access s.data with lock
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    s := newServer()
    go s.run()
    go s.run2()
    s.stop()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. Use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) instead.

Comment: Any docs about the behavior of `close()`? I haven't found that on golang spec.

Comment: Thank you guys for the info:)